# redis randomKey from from a specific value?

Tags: redis

I have many different keys. some start with "user USERNAME" and many others.

is there a way to get a random key from the "user *" ?

if so, how can i get like 5 different users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put all the usernames into a Redis set, then you could use the [SRANDMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/srandmember) command to randomly gets usernames from the set. Example from the documentation:

```
redis> SADD myset one two three
(integer) 3
redis> SRANDMEMBER myset
"three"
redis> SRANDMEMBER myset 2
1) "three"
2) "two"
```

The set seems to be the only [Redis data type](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) that can return random elements from the collection. You might have to process your data a little differently to do this.

Comment: i see. because i have my user details in hash, the only and best way is to make a set with all the ids in?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use a Set and store all your "user*" key names in it, as suggested by **@Sunil D**.

Alternatively, you could use a dedicated Redis database for your "user*" keys and then use the `RANDOMKEY` command to fetch keys from it. The nice thing about this is that you don't have to manage the Set of key names (i.e. add and remove to it whenever a key is created or deleted, respectively).

Note, however, that with both approaches, you'll have to check that the result you got wasn't returned earlier after each call to `SRANDMEMBER` or `RANDOMKEY` since both **do not** ensure that you'll get a different answer each time you invoke it.

Comment: Do you suggest alternative 1 or alternative 2? if alternative two, could you provide an example of a dedicated redis database ?

Comment: I think #2 is simpler. A dedicated Redis database is just another Redis server that you use for storing your "user*" keys. Do not use shared/numbered databases - these could be quite problematic, see here for more info: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances

Comment: do you have a chatroom? where i can ask some more redis questions, if you dont mind?

Comment: Not at all - we can even do one here somehow... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/81885/redis-randomkey-from-from-a-specific-value